# Flip animation only halfway through

Tags: iphone, animation, flip

I was wondering if it would be possible to make an animation that looks like the flip transition, but only animate it halfway through, so that the animation stops at the moment  when you you can't really see it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to animate the layer's `transform` property from it's default (`CATransform3DIdentity`) to a quarter-rotation around the Y axis. It should be something like this:

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2, 0, 1, 0);
    transform.m34 = 1.0 / -2000.0;
    self.view.layer.transform = transform;
  }];
```

The `m34` value is how you turn on perspective for a layer. Search for "m34 perspective" for many discussions of it.

Comment: Thank you for this, but the animation behaves kind of weird.. it cuts of a part of the view that is animated and then flips. Any suggestions?